# Background-image margin on button in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, background-image

Does someone know why there is a margin (about 1px) around the button background-image, only in Internet Explorer ?

Try this code in IE vs Firefox :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
        button {
            background: grey url("http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/images/red_square.png") 0px 0px repeat-x;
            border: 1px solid black;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>LOL</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how it is displayed on my computer in IE9 (in big size) :

[image: button with background-image margin in IE]

Notice : If I remove the (black) border, the margin disappears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differnet browsers have different definitions of the button tag (and other tags). In fact, Chrome have a margin of 2px. You can easily solved it by making margin explicit:

```
button {
    background: grey url("http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/images/red_square.png") 0px 0px repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0; /* or ex 1px */
}
```

**Update:**

I think it is the font-family (or the rendering of it) which is different, try:

```
button {
    background: grey url("http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/images/red_square.png") 0px 0px repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 24px;

    /* To get it exact */
    margin: 0; /* or ex 1px */
    padding: 0; /* or ex 1px */

    font-family: Consolas;
}
```

**Update:**
Without `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` I can reproduce the problem. And in this case IE is running in Quirks mode. Do you include the doctype when you test it?

Anyway, you just have to avoid quirks mode: http://www.google.dk/search?aq=0&oq=avoid+qui&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=avoid+quirks+mode
Ex avoid ANYTHING before doctype.

Comment: That's not the problem here. It's not about the margin around the whole button element (which can indeed be fixed with your answer), but about the margin around the background-image inside the button. See what I mean ?

Comment: @Yoot Ahh okay, I noted that in IE8 only. I'll delete this answer until I find a solution :)

Comment: Tried the font-family, the margin's still here. Is there anyway to post a picture on this site ? I could show you how it's displayed on my computer.

Comment: @Yoot Yes, there is a image button when you edit your question.

Comment: Arf need more than 10 reputation to post images :/

Comment: @Yoot I Gave you +1 on your question and now you should have +10 rep.

Comment: Yes, I included the doctype while testing. But you must be right about the Quirks mode, I just can't figure out why it is "enabled" on my IE...

Comment: Hit F12 and you get developer tools. And there you can verify that IE is running in Quirks mode.

Comment: The Browser mode is set to IE9 compatibility view. When I set it to Internet Explorer 8 / 9 it's OK. I just wonder why the default mode is set to "compatibility view" on my computer... Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Yoot Okay. If you use a newer standard such as XHTML 1 or 1.1 then it should be fixed. You can also force compatibility with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: @Yoot There might also be a difference for offline pages vs. online. Try to put it online :)

Comment: Actually I made this example cause I had the problem with an online website, so I don't think it's because of this. I'll try with a newer standard and tell you what I get. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't faced such problem with your code, probably this is because you ie version is older one.

Comment: Actually I updated it recently to IE9, and the problem was already present in IE7 and IE8 on my computer

Comment: I tested it on latest chrome, ie8 and mozill 5.0, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different generic style standards for different html elements. To avoid this problem (or defend against it the best you can!) you should really include a reset style sheet in all your sites to try and synchronise the styles of all browsers best you can. One of the greats I have found is Erics Archived thoughts:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

This typically does the trick (with a few little tweaks after a penultimate cross browser test).

Comment: Yes I know about css reset, already tried it too, but that didn't make that !§%ù$ margin disappear ^^